# finding the minimum value takes too much memory operations on GPU

Tags: c++, gpgpu, openacc

I have 9 2D arrays, and I want to calculate the minimum value of each element of the 8 arrays and store them in the 9th. I have wrote a code but it's taking much memory operations.
My GPU is Nvidia GTX 1060 and I am using OpenACC to accelerate.
could you please help me on how to optimize this code to find the minmum value with less operations ?
this is my code

```
    for (int i=1; i<(height); i++)
{
    for (int j=0; j <( width); j++)

    {
        ( thresh_array[i-1][j] < top_left[i-1][j])? :  thresh_array[i-1][j] = top_left[i-1][j];
        ( thresh_array[i-1][j] < top[i-1][j])? :  thresh_array[i-1][j] = top[i-1][j];
        ( thresh_array[i-1][j] < top_right[i-1][j])? :  thresh_array[i-1][j] = top_right[i-1][j];
        ( thresh_array[i-1][j] <left[i-1][j])? :  thresh_array[i-1][j] = left[i-1][j];
        ( thresh_array[i-1][j] < right[i-1][j])? :  thresh_array[i-1][j] = right[i-1][j];
        ( thresh_array[i-1][j] < bot[i-1][j])? :  thresh_array[i-1][j] = bot[i-1][j];
        ( thresh_array[i-1][j] < bot_left[i-1][j])? :  thresh_array[i-1][j] = bot_left[i-1][j];
        ( thresh_array[i-1][j] <bot_right[i-1][j])? :  thresh_array[i-1][j] = bot_right[i-1][j];
    }
}
```

ps. I'm new to programming in general.

Comment: I'm not sure that this will boost up your code but I would start with `i`: `for (int i = 0, n = height - 1; i < n; ++i) {`... When you changed the loop range you may replace every `[i-1]` with `[i]`. Btw. is it correct to stop the loop before `height - 1`? Without knowing more details I cannot be sure but it is looking suspicious somehow...

Comment: This is **very** obfuscated way to write `min`... And... Well, a compiler should optimize this, but just in case, try to find minimal value to a local variable and then store it to the destination array.

Comment: @Scheff it is ok, but it didn't boost my code. what I'm trying to do is to compare a pixel with its 8 neighbors and then find the smallest value of the 8, all of these values are double not int.

Comment: @MichaelNastenko I did find another way. using the same concept only comparing 3 values at a time. it did improve the memory operations and reduce memory dependency by a little bit. so now I wonder if there is a way to compare more elements with less lines of code.